# How do I complete this SQL code in Alteryx with the formula tool without directly selecting from the table?

Tags: sql, alteryx

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    LAG(orderdate, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY fullaccountnum, cin ORDER BY orderdate) AS previous_orderdate 
FROM 
    table.revenue_invoice_data
```

I've tried the expression below in the formula tool to no avail. I keep getting the error: syntax or semantic error analysis.

```
fullaccountnum == [fullaccountnum-1] && 
cin == [cin-1] ? [orderdate-1] : Null()
```

Comment: For a SQL `lag` function, try the MultiRow Formula tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Multi-Row Formula tool to get equivalent of `LAG` function. If the column name is `col1`, then the equivalent expression to be used in the Multi-Row Formula to access previous row's data is `[Row-1:col1]`

Answer (score 0):

The regular Formula tool can not be used across multiple rows. You'll have to use the Multi-Row Formula tool.